# How to use compareTo method with generic T type?

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable, compareto

I got this UML, maybe it helps. The only thing I'm using there is
the instance variable T[] list and the method f() which is method just for testing.

(edited)note: Ignore those overrided compareto methods in the UML, I tried to override the method but it didnt work because it was not comparing the t types.

[image]

These are my headers:

[image]

I have a class that represents a list, but I do not understand how to make it work with T types.
For example in my class Alist I have an instance variable called "list" which is a array of type T, I would like to compare this Type T objects inside another method called "f()" .

inside public static void:

```
ListInterface<String> myList =  new AList();

myList.add("a");

myList.add("b");

myList.add("c");

myList.f();
```

inside Alist.java:

```
public void f() {

    System.out.println( "a".compareTo("b")); //works 

    System.out.println(list[1].compareTo(list[2]));  //gives the error below

}
```

For the second print statement I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method compareTo(T) is undefined for the type T
```

Comment: `ListInterface<T> extends Comparable<T>` indicates that `ListInterface` is what's comparable, not `T`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was trying to override the method but it didn't work for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to compare the elements of **AList** class you should use your generics type like this `AList<T extends Comparable<T>>` and [bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) it.